# Securely hide jQuery result from user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcryption

Is it possible to generate a random number with jQuery, then post it to the server in a form without the user being able to find out the number? I know I can "hide" the output, but can I hide it from firebug too?

Could it be done with something like jCryption, or is this actually impossible with jQuery?

Comment: It's impossible with clientside code, as the code is always available to the client. Best you can do is obfuscation.

Comment: Why not generate the number on the server?

Comment: Why would you want this? The mere fact that it's generated on the client means that he has some control over it.

Comment: Even if it was possible to hide it, the user always can save the page locally. Once done, (s)he can edit it and submit manipulated (malicious) data to your server!

Answer (score 7):

Nothing you do on the client-side should ever be considered safe from the user's manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible. Every connection between the browser and the server can be intercepted by the user. Open your console in Chrome and open the 'Network' tab to see what I'm talking about.

Select anyone of those fancy looking rows: in the panel that just popped out on the left select "Headers". Tad'ah!

Under "query string params" you'll see all the informations your browser sent to the server for that request: you can see them URL encoded, or even well formatted.

If you send an Ajax request via jQuery, the sent parameters will appear there as well. If any random guy with free software can intercept sensible data, I'd recommend to compute this data elsewhere instead that on the browser.

I don't know what you're trying to do but if you have a number you don't want your user to know, that number should **only** travel on the server.

Comment: OP could compute value in browser, send to server via AJAX, and server could re-compute the value using received value as input. Simplest case: add a constant, say 27, to received value. Simple obfuscation, as suggested above by adeneo (who, btw, consistently provides excellent ideas). Paul Sullivan provides a more rigorous plan below. No matter what you do, an infinite number of Chinese hackers on an infinite number of typewriters could eventually decode the obfuscation, but one can "up" the barrier to entry.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want as you described but the way to do something similar is to have the server generate and return it for you encrypted.

The gist:

- $.ajax to post to server side script
- Server script generates i.e. Guid -> using server side encryption key generate encrypted Guid this will be quite hard to crack given a decent length key and the length of a guid)
- Return it to the $.ajax call.
- Then when the form is posted back the server can decrypt the form submission (as it and only it knows the encryption key

HTH if you hadnt already thought of it

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this, but could you give me some more details on how this would work? If the server posts an encryption key back to the random number script, can't the user then see the key used to encrypt it?  Is this similar to what jCryption does?

Comment: The key is never transmitted to the client. I assume yoou thought the key would be sent becuase the client needs to modify the encrypted number? If that is the case then you woud have to create server side routines for every 'modification' of the data that is encrypted. If the client needs to access/modify the data then there is no option other than to leave it unencrypte or possibly try hide it from prying eyes by using closures and mimicking data encapsulation in javascript but this would not garauntee that it was hidden away.

Comment: Sorry, no.. I meant guid not key. Surely if the user gets the guid and does the encryption, then he can reverse it?

Comment: What you're describing does sound a lot like jcryption (www.jcryption.org/faq/), how is it different?

Comment: The server side script (asp, php, perl, w/e) encrypts /decrypts the Guid but I think you want to access the data on the client side (.js) and if that is the case then you have little or no way of truly hiding the data as other posters have already said.

Comment: No, only the server needs to ever see the number, but it needs to be generated by the user.

Comment: okay so you would have the user generate and once input by the client it gets sent off to be encrypted by the server... If the user generates it why does it need to ever be encrypted? unless you are concerned about xss...

Comment: I was trying to have the user generate a random key pair, but only ever be able to see one of the keys. So, somehow I need to encrypt the second key before the user can see it. I'm pretty sure this is either impossible or really unreliable, so I'm rethinking the idea. Thanks for your input though.