# Securely hide jQuery result from user - 2

Tags: php, jquery, encryption

I know i've asked this question before ([Securely hide jQuery result from user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885600/securely-hide-jquery-result-from-user)), but i'm hoping to ask the same question and get a different answer...

Basically, I have a jQuery script that generates a random key pair. I need to get that key pair from the jQuery script to a php variable without the user being able to see it.

I've been told that this is impossible by a lot of people but I'd really like a 25th opinion.

From what I understand, this would infact be possible by using node.js with something like ssjquery or cheerio, but before I go that route, is there a simpler solution?

I have an idea and i'd just like to know if it would work.

Could I encrypt the data with an RSA public key as part of the jQuery script, then decrypt it on the server with the private key? I've tried this by adding phpseclib-jsbn-rsa encryption into the script, and it seems to work, but is there a way that the user could get the data before the encryption? https://github.com/mvhaen/phpseclib-jsbn-rsa  Also, would it makeany difference if I called the script with file_get_contents from a php page?

I just don't know enough about what's really going on in the process to judge if it'd work. So, if anyone could enlighten me that'd be great, or if you know of another way without using nodejs, jsdom, phantomjs, etc, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just generate the key pair via the php script in the first place?

Comment: That was my first thought, but these are not regular keys. The script is written in jQuery and I can't alter the script myself.

Comment: No, as far as I know you cannot achieve a high level of security with Javascript other than through obfuscation. I would rather suggest that you merely send the components that you use to build your key to a server side script and then generate the key there.

Comment: Regular Keys? If you can create these keys using jQuery, you can create them using PHP. This would be a far easier task than trying to create the keys in a users browser, and transferring them to the server without the user seeing...

Comment: They are wallet keys for a cryptocurrency a bit like bitcoin. I've spent some time looking at it and I really don't understand it enough to recreate it in PHP. I'm not saying it can't be done, i'm just saying that I can't do it. Right now my options are to generate a batch of these keys and serve them from a database, or use node.js. I just want to know if there is a better way WITHOUT rewriting the script

Comment: If you absolutely have to use jQuery, then node.js is your only option to securely generate these keys server side. There is no way to securely generate these in the browser without the user being able to grab them in some fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely have to use jQuery, then node.js is your only option to securely generate these keys server side. There is no way to securely generate these in the browser without the user being able to grab them in some fashion.

Comment: OK, thanks, i've done it with node.js for now, but i'll revisit it another time and have a crack at rewriting it in PHP.